# Why isn't too restrictive to consider a connection of the form $-iA$ in the magnetic Ginzburg-Landau model?

Tags: field-theory, superconductivity, gauge-invariance

I'm facing this equation as a mathematician, so the problem could easily be my lack of knowledge in physics.

In the magnetic Ginzburg-Landau model the energy has the form
$$
E(A,\phi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\left(|(d-iA)\phi|^2+\frac{1}{2}F_{jk}F_{jk}+\frac{1}{4}(1-|\phi|^2)^2\right)d^2x
$$
where $F_{jk}=\partial_jA_k-\partial_kA_j$, $\phi$ is a complex smooth function and $A$ is a **real** valued 1-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The first term of the energy is supposed to be the square norm of a linear connection $\nabla$ defined on the complex line bundle $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{C}$, applied to the smooth section $\phi$ of the same bundle.

In general, a connection of this type should have the form
$$
\nabla f= df+f\beta 
$$ 
where $\beta$ is a **complex**-valued 1-form. However, in the model this is required to have purely imaginary coefficients $(\beta=-iA)$. Isn't this restrictive?

I thought that this choice was to ensure gauge-invariance of the energy, but this still holds under the transformation
$$
(\phi,\beta)\to (\phi e^{i\alpha},\beta-id\alpha).
$$
Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Yes this is done. The covariant derivative acts on the scalar field. This is generalized in the EW standard model in the Higgs sector.